# How to write a Oracle function based on the data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table Employee which has data like

```
Employee_id | Name | M_date
------------+------+----------
1           | A    | 5/1/2013
2           | B    | 4/1/2014
3           | C    | 7/1/2015
4           | D    | 9/1/2015
5           | E    | 10/1/2020
6           | X    | 11/1/2019
```

I need to write an Oracle function which returns the employee working level by taking the `M_DATE` and `sysdate`(todays date).

The logic is as below (pseudo-code follows)

```
int nMonthDiff = (12 * (M_date year - Current year) + (M_date month - Current Month));

if (current year is greater than M_date year)
    then employee_level = 'employee moved to other divison'
else if (nMonthDiff <= 12) THEN employee_level = 12
else if (nMonthDiff <= 24) THEN employee_level = 11
else if (nMonthDiff <= 36) THEN employee_level = 10
else if (nMonthDiff <= 48) THEN employee_level = 9
else if (nMonthDiff <= 60) THEN employee_level = 8
else employee_level = 'junior'
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the level codes increment by one when the months increment by 12, integer division of the number of months will get you to the right scale for level codes.  Because the level codes decrease as the number of months increase, subtraction of the scaled code will reverse the scale of the level code.  Here's a query that will do it in Postgres:

```
select
employee_id,
case when extract(year from m_date) > extract(year from now()) then 'Moved to other division'
    else cast(12 - floor(abs(12 * (extract(year from m_date)-extract(year from now())) 
        + (extract(month from m_date) - extract(month from now()))) / 12) as character varying)
    end as level
from employee;
```

You will have to adapt it to Oracle yourself.

Comment: Replace `now()` with `current_date` for Oracle (or `sysdate`)

Answer (score 0):

By now, I imagine you already converted @rd_nielsen's answer for yourself. However it struck me that even if you were using PostGres it wasn't quite right, so I gave it a whirl.

```
Select
    diffs.Employee_id,
    diffs.emp_name,
    case
        when diffs.nYearDiff  >  0 then 'Moved to other division'
        when diffs.nMonthDiff > 60 then 'Junior'
        else TO_CHAR(GREATEST(12, 12 - FLOOR(diffs.nMonthDiff / 12)))
    end AS Employee_Level
FROM
    (
    SELECT
        my_employee.Employee_id,
        my_employee.emp_name,
        (extract(year from m_date) - extract(year from sysdate)) as nYearDiff,
        ((12 * (extract(year from m_date) - extract(year from sysdate))) + (extract(month from m_date) - extract(month from sysdate))) as nMonthDiff
    FROM
        my_employee
    ) diffs
```

This code borrows @rd_nielsen's insight that the intervals between is level are constant at 12, adds handling for when `nMonthDiff` is negative (using `GREATEST` and avoiding `ABS`), and also deals with your "junior" category.

What you actually asked for we as function, not a query, and so if you're reading this and do still want a function you can call like this: `level_at_date(M_Date, at_date)` or just `level(M_date)` then do say so, and I'll see whether my Oracle skills can stretch to that.

Comment: It's been a while, but did one of the answers here work for you? If so it'd be great if you could mark the best one as accepted.